# Cannot add epel repository on RHEL8.1

Tags: centos, repository, dnf

I am unable to install add epel repository. I did the following which work without errors:

```
# dnf install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-8.noarch.rpm

# ARCH=$( /bin/arch )
    subscription-manager repos --enable "codeready-builder-for-rhel-8-${ARCH}-rpms"
```

Now, if I list the repositories with `dnf repolist`, `epel` is  simply not listed. Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`epel` is normally enabled by default when the RPM for it is installed. If, for some reason it wasn't, you need to enable it but the command that you ran enabled the `codeready-builder` repo.

Run this command to enable `epel`:

```
dnf config-manager --enable epel
```

You can then run `dnf repolist` to see `epel` listed.